# Cubature on Wiener space

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ diffuses as,

$$
dX_t = \mu(X_t)\, dt + \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t
$$

and,

$$
g(t,x)=\mathbb{E}[g(T,X_T)\vert\mathcal{F}_t]
$$

By Feynman-Kac we have,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(t,x)=-\mathcal{L}g(t,x)
$$

Where,

$$
\mathcal{L}=\mu(X_t)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(X_t)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}
$$

Why is it that we are allowed to approximate $X_t$ by,

$$
X_t = e^{\mathcal{L}\sqrt{t}Z}X_0
$$

Where $Z\sim N[0,1]$?

EDIT: For those interested, there was a mistake in the question. This is a notation I'm not used to, since typically one knows $X_t$ has no time derivative almost surely. First, let $g(t,X_t)=X_t$ so that,

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}X_t = -\mathcal{L}X_t
$$

Now choose differential operators $V_0$ and $V_1$ so that,

$$
\mathcal{L} = V_0+\frac{1}{2}V_1^2
$$

Then apparently cubature of degree 3 is the approximation,

$$
X_t = e^{V_0 t + V_1\sqrt{t}Z}X_0
$$

Comment: Could clarifly the expression $\mathcal{L}\sqrt{t}Z$ in your last equation ? Best regards